# What is the "natural" ($\natural$) symbol?

Tags: notation

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07021) talks about "$M^\natural$-concave functions". The paper defines what an M$^\natural$-concave function is, but, I would like to know specifically what does the $\natural$ symbol mean? Why is it called "natural" and where else in mathematics is it used?

Comment: See [Natural sign (in music)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_(music)#Natural_sign).

Comment: [This post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32082/how-to-write-larger-natural-symbol) on TeX.SE implies that the OP was wishing to use it as a boundary connected sum in analogy to how $\sum$ is used for ordinary summation.  Looking at other texts about boundary connected sums however, I see $\#$ or some other variation being used instead.

Comment: Should we read for example M natural?

Comment: It's the natural sign from music, to undo a sharp or flat set by the key signature. Unsure how it's used in math. Here's the Unicode for the symbol: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266e/index.htm